# NSTextView end editing action like NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

How can I detect an end editing action on a NSTextView, just like on NSTextField ? I can not see it as an action or in its delegate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can register for notifications, such as `NSTextDidEndEditingNotification`.

If you want to use the delegate pattern, then you should check the `NSTextDelegate` protocol. Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008624). The method sent on end editing is `textDidEndEditing:`.

`NSTextView` is a subclass of `NSText`, so it is a good idea to check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstext_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that class, too.

### Example

`NSTextView` has a `NSTextViewDelegate` property you can use to be notified about changes. The delegate methods are mere convenience methods to obtain the "end editing" notification, unlike `control:textShouldEndEditing` you may know from `NSTextField`, for example.

```
class SomeViewController: NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate {

    var textView: NSTextView!

    func loadView() {

        super.loadView()

        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textDidBeginEditing(notification: NSNotification) {

        guard let editor = notification.object as? NSTextView else { return }

        // ...
    }

    func textDidEndEditing(notification: NSNotification) {

        guard let editor = notification.object as? NSTextView else { return }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example?